# Phase correlation with Open Cv

Tags: image-processing, opencv, signal-processing

I want to calculate phase correlation of function in OpenCV. I've found http://nashruddin.com/phase-correlation-function-in-opencv.html but there is used some other library and I want to do it with OpenCV.

My problem is differen cause I want to calculate phase correlation of two arrays, both 360 elements.
I tried to evaluate from documentation how to do it, but I don't know if my method is good.
My R matrix isn't normalized, how to normalize it and is it necessary?
If you give me some examples I would be grateful.
My function to do this task:

```
void calcPhaseCorrelation(int* x1, int* x2){
    Mat array1 = Mat(1,360,DataType<float>::type); 
    Mat array2 = Mat(1,360,DataType<float>::type);

    uchar* begin = array1.data;
    uchar* end = begin + (array1.step.p[0]/ sizeof(float)) * array1.size().height;
    uchar *ptr = begin;

    int ctr1 = 0, ctr2 = 0; //control in loops
    while(ptr<end)
    {
       *ptr = (float)x1[ctr1];
       ctr1++;
       ptr++;
    }

    begin = array2.data;
    end = begin + (array2.step.p[0]/ sizeof(float)) * array2.size().height;
    ptr = begin;
    while(ptr<end)
    {
        *ptr = x2[ctr2];
        ctr2++;
        ptr++;
    }

    Mat outputArray;
    outputArray.create(abs(array1.rows - array2.rows)+1, 
        abs(array1.cols - array2.cols)+1, array1.type());
    Size dftSize;
    dftSize.width = getOptimalDFTSize(array1.cols + array2.cols - 1);
    dftSize.height = getOptimalDFTSize(array1.rows + array2.rows - 1);

    Mat resultA(dftSize, array1.type(), Scalar::all(0));
    Mat resultB(dftSize, array2.type(), Scalar::all(0));
    dft(array1,resultA);
    dft(array2,resultB);

    Mat R;
    mulSpectrums(resultA,resultB,R,DFT_ROWS,true);
    Mat NormR;
normalize(R,NormR);
    idft(NormR,outputArray);
    double minVal, maxVal;
    Point minLoc, maxLoc;
    minMaxLoc(outputArray,&minVal,&maxVal,&minLoc,&maxLoc);

    std::cout<<"Min value: "<<minVal<<", max value: "<<maxVal<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Min loc x: "<<minLoc.x<<", min loc y: "<<minLoc.y<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Max loc x: "<<maxLoc.x<<", max loc y: "<<maxLoc.y<<std::endl;
}
```

I know that code is not clear etc., but it's only fast test. I want to know if method is correct. But also there every advice is appreciated.

//Edit:
I used mevatron code and get #QNAN also while debugging seen that in function that it does not find a peak, value is (-1,-1).
Function I'm using with new OpenCV correlation function:

```
void phaseCorrelationOpenCvTrunk(int* array1, int* array2)
{
    Mat hann;

    vector<double> arr1, arr2;

    for(int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
    {
        arr1.push_back((double)array1[i]);
        arr2.push_back((double)array2[i]);
    }


    Mat firstArray = Mat(arr1);
    Mat secondArray = Mat(arr2);

    std::cout<<"Type control: "<<firstArray.type()<<std::endl;

    createHanningWindow(hann, firstArray.size(), CV_64F);

    Point2d shift = phaseCorrelate(firstArray, secondArray,hann);

    std::cout<<"shift: "<<shift.x<<";"<<shift.y<<std::endl;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have actually implemented this method for OpenCV, but unfortunately it is only in the SVN trunk at this stage.

[Here](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/phase_corr.cpp) is a sample using the new method.

If you would like to reference my implementation of it, you can find that [here](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/phasecorr.cpp).

Also, [here](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/modules/imgproc/test/test_pc.cpp) is the test case for an additional example of using it.

If you would like to use the trunk you can get a hold of it doing this:

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv opencv-trunk
```

[Here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation) is the CMake build guide for Linux. [Here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation) is the build guide for Windows.

**EDIT :** 
Got a patch for you :)

I found a few bugs in my code as well, so they should be corrected now. It also should support 1D phase-correlation now. I also found an issue with the `cv::sqrt()` function causing some -nan's to show up even though `std::sqrt()` did not. I'm guessing it's either a bug with OpenCV, or just an accuracy issue. Haven't dug into it enough to find out though.

Unfortunately, you can't just use `svn update` to get my latest changes because I have to wait for the OpenCV developers to apply this patch. So, instead of you having to wait on that here is a patch you can apply to the `$(OPENCV_SRC)/modules/imgproc/src/phasecorr.cpp` file. Save this file as something like `phasecorr.patch`, and place it in the root of the OpenCV source directory. [Here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-patch.html) is a short TortoiseSVN guide for creating/applying patches from/to source trees.

```
Index: modules/imgproc/src/phasecorr.cpp
===================================================================
--- modules/imgproc/src/phasecorr.cpp   (revision 6971)
+++ modules/imgproc/src/phasecorr.cpp   (working copy)
@@ -83,8 +83,8 @@

                 for( j = 1; j <= rows - 2; j += 2 )
                 {
-                    dataDst[j*stepDst] = (float)((double)dataSrc[j*stepSrc]*dataSrc[j*stepSrc] +
-                                         (double)dataSrc[(j+1)*stepSrc]*dataSrc[(j+1)*stepSrc]);
+                    dataDst[j*stepDst] = (float)std::sqrt((double)dataSrc[j*stepSrc]*dataSrc[j*stepSrc] +
+                                                          (double)dataSrc[(j+1)*stepSrc]*dataSrc[(j+1)*stepSrc]);
                 }

                 if( k == 1 )
@@ -103,7 +103,7 @@

             for( j = j0; j < j1; j += 2 )
             {
-                dataDst[j] = (float)((double)dataSrc[j]*dataSrc[j] + (double)dataSrc[j+1]*dataSrc[j+1]);
+                dataDst[j] = (float)std::sqrt((double)dataSrc[j]*dataSrc[j] + (double)dataSrc[j+1]*dataSrc[j+1]);
             }
         }
     }
@@ -127,8 +127,8 @@

                 for( j = 1; j <= rows - 2; j += 2 )
                 {
-                    dataDst[j*stepDst] = dataSrc[j*stepSrc]*dataSrc[j*stepSrc] +
-                                         dataSrc[(j+1)*stepSrc]*dataSrc[(j+1)*stepSrc];
+                    dataDst[j*stepDst] = std::sqrt(dataSrc[j*stepSrc]*dataSrc[j*stepSrc] +
+                                                   dataSrc[(j+1)*stepSrc]*dataSrc[(j+1)*stepSrc]);
                 }

                 if( k == 1 )
@@ -147,13 +147,10 @@

             for( j = j0; j < j1; j += 2 )
             {
-                dataDst[j] = dataSrc[j]*dataSrc[j] + dataSrc[j+1]*dataSrc[j+1];
+                dataDst[j] = std::sqrt(dataSrc[j]*dataSrc[j] + dataSrc[j+1]*dataSrc[j+1]);
             }
         }
     }
-
-    // do batch sqrt to use SSE optimizations...
-    cv::sqrt(dst, dst);
 }

 static void divSpectrums( InputArray _srcA, InputArray _srcB, OutputArray _dst, int flags, bool conjB)
@@ -196,9 +193,9 @@
             {
                 if( k == 1 )
                     dataA += cols - 1, dataB += cols - 1, dataC += cols - 1;
-                dataC[0] = dataA[0] / dataB[0];
+                dataC[0] = dataA[0] / (dataB[0] + eps);
                 if( rows % 2 == 0 )
-                    dataC[(rows-1)*stepC] = dataA[(rows-1)*stepA] / dataB[(rows-1)*stepB];
+                    dataC[(rows-1)*stepC] = dataA[(rows-1)*stepA] / (dataB[(rows-1)*stepB] + eps);
                 if( !conjB )
                     for( j = 1; j <= rows - 2; j += 2 )
                     {
@@ -239,9 +236,9 @@
         {
             if( is_1d && cn == 1 )
             {
-                dataC[0] = dataA[0] / dataB[0];
+                dataC[0] = dataA[0] / (dataB[0] + eps);
                 if( cols % 2 == 0 )
-                    dataC[j1] = dataA[j1] / dataB[j1];
+                    dataC[j1] = dataA[j1] / (dataB[j1] + eps);
             }

             if( !conjB )
@@ -281,9 +278,9 @@
             {
                 if( k == 1 )
                     dataA += cols - 1, dataB += cols - 1, dataC += cols - 1;
-                dataC[0] = dataA[0] / dataB[0];
+                dataC[0] = dataA[0] / (dataB[0] + eps);
                 if( rows % 2 == 0 )
-                    dataC[(rows-1)*stepC] = dataA[(rows-1)*stepA] / dataB[(rows-1)*stepB];
+                    dataC[(rows-1)*stepC] = dataA[(rows-1)*stepA] / (dataB[(rows-1)*stepB] + eps);
                 if( !conjB )
                     for( j = 1; j <= rows - 2; j += 2 )
                     {
@@ -323,9 +320,9 @@
         {
             if( is_1d && cn == 1 )
             {
-                dataC[0] = dataA[0] / dataB[0];
+                dataC[0] = dataA[0] / (dataB[0] + eps);
                 if( cols % 2 == 0 )
-                    dataC[j1] = dataA[j1] / dataB[j1];
+                    dataC[j1] = dataA[j1] / (dataB[j1] + eps);
             }

             if( !conjB )
@@ -354,31 +351,57 @@
 static void fftShift(InputOutputArray _out)
 {
     Mat out = _out.getMat();
-    
+
+    if(out.rows == 1 && out.cols == 1)
+    {
+        // trivially shifted.
+        return;
+    }
+
     vector<Mat> planes;
     split(out, planes);
-    
+
     int xMid = out.cols >> 1;
     int yMid = out.rows >> 1;
-    
-    for(size_t i = 0; i < planes.size(); i++)
+
+    bool is_1d = xMid == 0 || yMid == 0;
+
+    if(is_1d)
     {
-        // perform quadrant swaps...
-        Mat tmp;
-        Mat q0(planes[i], Rect(0,    0,    xMid, yMid));
-        Mat q1(planes[i], Rect(xMid, 0,    xMid, yMid));
-        Mat q2(planes[i], Rect(0,    yMid, xMid, yMid));
-        Mat q3(planes[i], Rect(xMid, yMid, xMid, yMid));
-        
-        q0.copyTo(tmp);
-        q3.copyTo(q0);
-        tmp.copyTo(q3);
-        
-        q1.copyTo(tmp);
-        q2.copyTo(q1);
-        tmp.copyTo(q2);
+        xMid = xMid + yMid;
+
+        for(size_t i = 0; i < planes.size(); i++)
+        {
+            Mat tmp;
+            Mat half0(planes[i], Rect(0, 0, xMid, 1));
+            Mat half1(planes[i], Rect(xMid, 0, xMid, 1));
+
+            half0.copyTo(tmp);
+            half1.copyTo(half0);
+            tmp.copyTo(half1);
+        }
     }
-    
+    else
+    {
+        for(size_t i = 0; i < planes.size(); i++)
+        {
+            // perform quadrant swaps...
+            Mat tmp;
+            Mat q0(planes[i], Rect(0,    0,    xMid, yMid));
+            Mat q1(planes[i], Rect(xMid, 0,    xMid, yMid));
+            Mat q2(planes[i], Rect(0,    yMid, xMid, yMid));
+            Mat q3(planes[i], Rect(xMid, yMid, xMid, yMid));
+
+            q0.copyTo(tmp);
+            q3.copyTo(q0);
+            tmp.copyTo(q3);
+
+            q1.copyTo(tmp);
+            q2.copyTo(q1);
+            tmp.copyTo(q2);
+        }
+    }
+
     merge(planes, out);
 }

@@ -548,38 +571,67 @@
     int rows = dst.rows;
     int cols = dst.cols;

+    bool is_1d = rows == 1 || cols == 1;
+
+    if(is_1d)
+    {
+        cols = cols + rows - 1;
+    }
+
     if(dst.depth() == CV_32F)
     {
         float* dstData = (float*)dst.data;

-        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
+        if(is_1d)
         {
-            double wr = 0.5 * (1.0f - cos(2.0f * CV_PI * (double)i / (double)(rows - 1)));
-            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
+            for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
             {
-                double wc = 0.5 * (1.0f - cos(2.0f * CV_PI * (double)j / (double)(cols - 1)));
-                dstData[i*cols + j] = (float)(wr * wc);
+                double w = 0.5 * (1.0f - cos(2.0f * CV_PI * (double)i / (double)(cols - 1)));
+                dstData[i] = (float)w;
             }
         }
+        else
+        {
+            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
+            {
+                double wr = 0.5 * (1.0f - cos(2.0f * CV_PI * (double)i / (double)(rows - 1)));
+                for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
+                {
+                    double wc = 0.5 * (1.0f - cos(2.0f * CV_PI * (double)j / (double)(cols - 1)));
+                    dstData[i*cols + j] = (float)(wr * wc);
+                }
+            }

-        // perform batch sqrt for SSE performance gains
-        cv::sqrt(dst, dst);
+            // perform batch sqrt for SSE performance gains
+            cv::sqrt(dst, dst);
+        }
     }
     else
     {
         double* dstData = (double*)dst.data;

-        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
+        if(is_1d)
         {
-            double wr = 0.5 * (1.0 - cos(2.0 * CV_PI * (double)i / (double)(rows - 1)));
-            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
+            for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
             {
-                double wc = 0.5 * (1.0 - cos(2.0 * CV_PI * (double)j / (double)(cols - 1)));
-                dstData[i*cols + j] = wr * wc;
+                double w = 0.5 * (1.0f - cos(2.0f * CV_PI * (double)i / (double)(cols - 1)));
+                dstData[i] = w;
             }
         }
+        else
+        {
+            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
+            {
+                double wr = 0.5 * (1.0 - cos(2.0 * CV_PI * (double)i / (double)(rows - 1)));
+                for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
+                {
+                    double wc = 0.5 * (1.0 - cos(2.0 * CV_PI * (double)j / (double)(cols - 1)));
+                    dstData[i*cols + j] = wr * wc;
+                }
+            }

-        // perform batch sqrt for SSE performance gains
-        cv::sqrt(dst, dst);
+            // perform batch sqrt for SSE performance gains
+            cv::sqrt(dst, dst);
+        }
     }
 }
```

Finally, here is a code sample of using the 1D phase correlation I was using.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat firstArray = Mat::zeros(Size(360, 1), CV_64F);
    Mat secondArray = Mat::zeros(Size(360, 1), CV_64F);

    for(int i = 0; i < firstArray.cols; i++)
    {
        if(i < 8)
        {
            firstArray.at<double>(0, i) = 1;
        }

        if(i < 6)
        {
            secondArray.at<double>(0, i) = 1;
        }
    }

    Mat hann;
    createHanningWindow(hann, firstArray.size(), CV_64F);

    Point2d shift = phaseCorrelate(firstArray, secondArray, hann);

    std::cout<< "shift: " << shift.x << ";" << shift.y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You should see an output of (-2, 0.5). The `y` value will always be 0.5 in the 1D case because that would be midway through the only row.

Hope that is helpful to you!

Comment: Have some problem with using this function. I have edited my question.

Comment: @krzych I will take a look at that for you when I get home. I believe the problem maybe the matrices are only 1 dimensional. I never tested that case. Can you check to make sure that `opencv_test_imgproc` (I think that's the name) completes without errors?

Comment: Oh, and can you also run `opencv_test_core` to make sure it passes. There is a bug with gcc 4.6.1 that will cause the DFT optimizations to fail depending on what optimizations you enabled during the build.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it already test succeeded. Ok I will run opencv_test_core too, and write what's result. I'm using VisualStudio and it's compilator.

Comment: did you test this code on real data? for example http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8841028/FFT%20template%20matching/test%20images/im1.png http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8841028/FFT%20template%20matching/test%20images/im2.png  you algorithm gives (17.5,20) but ImageJ stittching plugin (20,23). so seems it work not subpixel accurate.

Comment: Which version of OpenCV are you using? I ran the same images and got a phase shift of (20.1918, 22.5675) which is more accurate than ImageJ.

Comment: I'm using 2.3.0 , but can test it on 2.4.3 soon.

Comment: I tried prebuild 2.4.3 and it works for previous images, but it doesn't work for images that have 20% overlap here is my code http://codepaste.ru/12840/ I use images of different size so I padd images with zeros, maybe there are some border or cycle problems? ImageJ gives (424 0) peak.

Comment: Can you post the images you were testing with?

Comment: I ran my own test with 20% overlap (images were 200x200 with 40 horizontal pixels overlap and 200 vertical overlap). `phaseCorrelate` with Hanning window detected (37.2637, 1.42088) reasonable considering the size of the overlap compared to the window ramp. Without Hanning I get (39.9868, 0.133814), so a more accurate shift due to no window ramp. But, in most real-world cases windowing helps rather than hurts.